# css relative footer and fixed sidebar overlap each other

Tags: css

I researched a lot and could not find the solution for my problem. The footer overlaps the fixed sidebar. I want to prevent divs overlapping each other. Could you please help me. Z-index does not solve the problem.

```
#sidebar {
    margin: 140px 0px 0px 572px;
    float: right;
    width: 226px;
    position: fixed;
}
#footer {
    clear: both;
    height: 55px;
    width: 100%;    
    position: relative;    
}
```

Comment: Could you share fiddle?

Comment: you  can hide footer when you open sidebar. $('#footer').hide() and show it when sidebar closed.$('#footer').show()

Comment: i would like to do it with css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your sidebar opaque by giving it a background color or image.

for example: https://jsfiddle.net/a3t22856/

The piece I added is:

```
background-color: white;
```

Comment: did not work and in your fiddle sidebar overlaps footer as well

Comment: You mentioned z index so I thought you wanted to make one sit 'on top' of the other rather than overlap and see both. 

If you want to prevent the overlap altogether, you should set widths for the divs so that they do not overlap.